# How can I hide "this"

Tags: javascript

```js
function $(selector) {

  var resultObject = {
    hide: function() {
      if (selector == this) {
        selector.style.visibility = "hidden";
      }

    }
  };

  return resultObject;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="hide myself with my jquery " onclick="$(this).hide();" />
```

How can check if the selector is "this" so I can hide him.. Please consider that I have to rebuild the hide function so I am not allowed to use any Jquery functions...

Comment: Use a function in `onclick` and pass it the parameter of `this` instead

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery though?

Comment: How in the world did you come up with this **bizarre** code?

Comment: @vsync to me it looks like a jQuery plugin without using jQuery. Maybe he wants to write his own library.

Comment: @empiric - I highly doubt that. to me it looks a novice question, asked in a novice way, which cannot possibly be of a person building a library.

Comment: *'Please consider that I have to rebuild the hide function so I am not allowed to use any Jquery functions'* if you overwrite such a basic method as `hide` in jQuery, and change its behaviour, your just asking for trouble. And if this is an attempt to write your own library, to "replace" jquery for you, your approach is bloated. Take a look at inheritance, add the "selected nodes" to the instance, and all the functions to the prototype, instead of creating **a new copy of every function** with each call to `$()`, just to call one of them

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to compare to `this` at all, since you want it to work to whatever you pass to `$`. Just leave out the `if`:

```js
function $(selector) {
    var resultObject = {
        hide: function () {
            selector.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    };
    return resultObject;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="hide myself with my jquery " onclick="$(this).hide();" />
```

Now, if your selector argument could be something else than a DOM element, but a CSS selector, then you need to test the argument for its data type. Be aware also that CSS selectors can represent more than one element, so if you want to deal with that as well, you'll need a loop.

Here is an example how you could implement this functionality:

```js
function $(selector) {
    var nodes = typeof selector === "string" 
        ? Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))
        : [selector];
    var resultObject = {
        hide: function () {
            nodes.forEach(function (node) {
                node.style.visibility = "hidden";
            });
        }
    };
    return resultObject;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="hide all divs with my jquery " 
       onclick="$('div').hide();" />
<div>div 1</div>
<div>div 2</div>
```

The next challenge would be to make this chainable, which you can do by putting all necessary state in *resultObject* and returning that on every method:

```js
function $(selector) {
    var resultObject = {
        nodes: typeof selector === "string" 
                ? Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))
                : [selector],
        hide: function () {
            resultObject.nodes.forEach(function (node) {
                node.style.visibility = "hidden";
            });
            return resultObject;
        },
        text: function (txt) {
            resultObject.nodes.forEach(function (node) {
                node.textContent = txt;
            });
            return resultObject;
        },
        color: function (colorCode) {
            resultObject.nodes.forEach(function (node) {
                node.style.color = colorCode;
            });
            return resultObject;
        }
    };
    return resultObject;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="color and put text in divs with my jquery " 
       onclick="$('div').color('red').text('clicked!');" />
<div>div 1</div>
<div>div 2</div>
```

This is not optimal, as you recreate the *resultObject* with every call of *$*. So you could look into improving on that. Then there should be ways to filter results, find elements below the selected node(s), ... etc.

But we are digressing. Before you know it you're really writing a library. ;-)

Comment: Talk about "over complicating!" :-)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're over complicating things. This can be achieved by simply giving your button a class:

```
  <input type="button" value="hide myself with my jquery " class="hideme"/>
```

And then creating a click handler in your JS:

```
$('.hideme').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: I don't think the Asker is looking for this.

Answer (score 4):

this here is pointing to window object.

you can change the scope of this using call/apply

check the following snippet

```js
function $(selector) {


  var resultObject = {
    hide: function() {
      this.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  };

  return resultObject;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="hide myself with my jquery " onclick="$(this).hide.call(this);" />
```

Hope it helps

Comment: let say I want to check it the selector is for example an id (checking with .charAt(0)) so I still need to check what the selector is...

Comment: yaa then you need to have the ifcondition to check what the selector is

Answer (score 2):

OT, since others have already pointed out, that you seem to (over-)complicate things, 
a different approach to your code:

```js
// a utility ...
var style = (prop, value) => node => (node && node.style[prop] = value, node);
// ... in action ...
var hide = style("visibility", "hidden");
```

```html
<!-- ... and a possible way to use it -->
<input type="button" value="hide myself with my jquery " onclick="hide(this)" />
```